# My custom normalizer doesn't get executed

Tags: 8

I'm building a REST api with Drupal 8 and I want to override the normalizer for the Formated Text field type.

I started with this example module: https://github.com/jazzdrive3/example_normalizer

**example_normalizer.services.yml**

```
services:
  example_normalizer.normalizer.formatted_text.json:
    class: Drupal\example_normalizer\Normalizer\FormattedTextNormalizer
    tags:
      # Give it a priority higher than the default jsonapi service
      # serializer.normalizer.field_item.jsonapi
      - { name: normalizer, priority: 22 }
```

**FormattedTextNormalizer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\example_normalizer\Normalizer;

use Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\FieldItemNormalizer;
use Drupal\text\Plugin\Field\FieldType\TextItemBase;
use Drupal\jsonapi\Normalizer\Value\FieldItemNormalizerValue;
use Drupal\filter\Entity\FilterFormat;
use Drupal\filter\Plugin\Filter\FilterHtml;

class FormattedTextNormalizer extends FieldItemNormalizer {

  protected $supportedInterfaceOrClass = TextItemBase::class;

  public function normalize($field_item, $format = NULL, array $context = [])
  {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\TypedData\TypedDataInterface $property */
    $values = [];
    // We normalize each individual property, so each can do their own casting,
    // if needed.
    foreach ($field_item as $property_name => $property) {
      if ($property_name == 'value') {
        $value = $property->getValue();
        $format = FilterFormat::load($field_item->format);

        $filter = $format->filters()->get('filter_html');
        $property = $filter->process($value, 'en')->getProcessedText();
      }

      $values[$property_name] = "HELLO";
    }

    if (isset($context['langcode'])) {
      $values['lang'] = $context['langcode'];
    }
    return new FieldItemNormalizerValue($values);
  }
}
```

But my test string "HELLO" doesn't get printed out in the json.
Also, the documentation about overriding normalizers is very rare and the few articles I found say different things (especially about the `example_normalizer.normalizer.formatted_text.json` key in services.yml).

Some say it should start with `serializer.`, some other say it should start with `example_normalizer.`... anyway I'm a bit lost here...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Looking to the tests is probably your best bet - there's only one in core, in core/modules/serialization/tests/modules/field_normalization_test. It's very bare-bones, so it should be easy to copy that as a base to work from (or compare it with your code to hopefully spot the inconsistency). Right now it looks like the only difference is using `serializer` as the service name prefix. Also check the silly things; make sure the module is enabled, make sure you're clearing cache after making changes to .services.yml, and make sure `$values[$property_name]` contains what it should before returning

Comment: I've only ever done this with my own typed data data types and specifying a fully-namespaced interface as a string for supportedInterfaceOrClass. I've never had to override the core normalizer process other than that.

Comment: @mradcliffe Would you be able to add a quick example as an answer? That sounds like it would be a good alternative

Comment: Looking at my xero.list_normalizer, I set the priority to 10 because I guess I did need to override ItemList normalization. @Clive, I'm looking into an answer.

Comment: I haven't really worked with jsonapi because it doesn't integrate with typed data (only entity normalization) and seemed really hard to even contribute that back without delaying its introduction into core so I gave up learning it. This theoretically should be possible, but I think it's jsonapi that's the issue here.